# Is there any make command, to tell the gcc to search for header files?

Tags: makefile

I need your help to prevent me from sitting hours and hours on a make project.

I trying myself on a bigger .cpp project. Therefore is here my folder structure:

```
myproj
  |
  |____Makefile
  |____main.cpp
  |____init.cpp
  |____end.cpp
  |____init.h
  |____end.h
  |____Dependencies
           |____biggerlib
                   |____bin   
                   |____include
                           |____biggerLib1
                           |____biggerLib2
                           |____biggerLib
                                   |____biggerLibrary.h
                                   |____Lib2.h
                                   |____Lib3.h
                                   |____AnotherDirWithFiles1
                                   |____AnotherDirWithFiles2
                                   |____AnotherDirWithFiles3
                                                |____etc.
                   |____src
                   |____makestuff
                           |____...
                           |____...
                                   |____...
                           |____...
                   |____codestuff
                           |____...
                           |____...
                                   |____...
                           |____...
                   |____datastuff
                           |____...
                           |____...
                                   |____...
                           |____...
                   |____Examples
                           |____...
                           |____...
                                   |____...
                           |____...
                   |____etc.
```

I guess you can imagine my folder structure now.

so till now i always had a error warning by gcc because it couldnt find my header files in my subfolder structure.
So i had to bind them all by themself into my makefile. 
This is way too much work, so i wish you can help me to find a solution to tell gcc to implement all of the header files right behind the Dependencies/biggerlib folder.

Thank yall for your help!!

Comment: No, `make` itself has no facility for searching for anything.  There are certainly ways to write and arrange both source code and makefiles to ease expressing header paths to the compiler, however, and this is what you should be doing.  There are also tools such as Autoconf and CMake that are intended for adapting the build process to diverse build systems, and these *could* be used to scan your own code base, but why?  You don't need to analyze your code base because you're in control of it!

Comment: Are you sure that no two header files have the same name?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try. First, find the header files:

```
find Dependencies/biggerlib -name "*.h"
```

This should produce:

```
Dependencies/biggerlib/include/biggerLib/biggerLibrary.h
Dependencies/biggerlib/include/biggerLib/Lib2.h
Dependencies/biggerlib/include/biggerLib/Lib3.h
Dependencies/biggerlib/somewhereElse/anotherLib.h
```

**Once this is working perfectly,** you can put a line in your makefile to capture it:

```
HEADERS := $(shell find Dependencies/biggerlib -name "*.h")
$(info $(HEADERS))
```

This should produce:

```
Dependencies/biggerlib/include/biggerLib/biggerLibrary.h Dependencies/biggerlib/include/biggerLib/Lib2.h Dependencies/biggerlib/include/biggerLib/Lib3.h Dependencies/biggerlib/somewhereElse/anotherLib.h
```

**Once this is working perfectly,** you can remove the filenames with `dir` and the redundancies with `sort`:

```
INC_DIRS := $(sort $(dir $(HEADERS)))
$(info $(INC_DIRS))
```

This should produce:

```
Dependencies/biggerlib/include/biggerLib/ Dependencies/biggerlib/somewhereElse/
```

**Once this is working perfectly,** you can tell Make to search these directories for header files as prerequisites:

```
vpath %.h $(INC_DIRS)
```

and/or tell the compiler to search them for header files to include:

```
$(CCX) $(addprefix -I, $(INC_DIRS)) ...
```